# Binding an image within a view bound by multiple viewmodels not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi I have window below that is bound to a viewmodel that contains multiple viewmodels as you can see below

```
<Window
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:TestProject.ViewModels"
```

I then set the DataContext of the Window to a `TestViewModel` as shown below

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:TestViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

I then set the binding of an Image within this window to `TestImage` which is found in the `TestModel` found within the `TestViewModel` Here is the code for the binding in Xaml and the Image get/set within the Model

Xaml:

```
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=TestModel.TestImage}" />
```

EDIT Entire`TestModel` added instead by request

```
public class Coupon : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private static DateTime _selectedDay = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime SelectedDay
    {
        get { return _selectedDay; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_selectedDay)) return;
            _selectedDay = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDay");
        }
    }


     private BitmapImage _testImage;
        public BitmapImage TestImage
        {
            get { return _testImage; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _testImage)) return;
                _testImage= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TestImage");
            }
        }


    private static bool _isNeeded = true;

    public bool IsNeeded
    {
        get { return _guaranteeEarlyPrices; }
        set { _guaranteeEarlyPrices = value; }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

The image always gets set and returned ok in code but does not appear in the view at all when running which suggests there is something wrong with my binding but I cannot see where as its a pretty simple binding.

Anyone know why this is or can they tell me where I've went wrong with the binding?

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in Visual Studio's Output pane?

Comment: You really should paste your `TestModel` code. I think that may be the source of the problem. And also, what causes the various properties involved (`TestModel` and `TestImage`) to change? Are change notifications set up for everything in the whole chain?

Comment: There are no binding errors in the output pane as far as I can see and I will paste the model code now. The properties are both change by a command executing, the command sets the property of `TestImage` to a `BitmapImage` converted from a `Bitmap` (I know that code work as its been used before on several `BitmapImages` and all worked)

Answer (score 0):

When you create/load the BitmapImage set `bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`.